# Bounding $ \max_{j \in \{1, \cdots, N\}} |\frac{e^{r_j\eta_1}}{\sum_{k=1}^N e^{r_k\eta_1}} - \frac{e^{r_j\eta_2}}{\sum_{k=1}^N e^{r_k\eta_2}}|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $r \in \mathbb{R}^N$, $0 < \eta_1< \eta_2 <+\infty$.
I am looking to bound, if possible in terms of the difference $h = \eta_2 - \eta_1$, the following quantity: $$ \max_{j \in \{1, \cdots, N\}} \left|\frac{e^{r_j\eta_1}}{\sum_{k=1}^N e^{r_k\eta_1}} - \frac{e^{r_j\eta_2}}{\sum_{k=1}^N e^{r_k\eta_2}}\right|.$$
Obviously, a crude bound is 1, but having a bound with $h$ would be better.

We can consider $h$ to be small.